# Web client Soap versionMismatch error c#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

Hi I am new at WCF Soap services, I need to connect to a webserver use Xml-Rpc. First I tried to connect and got an error about "xml-rpc encoded" then I added Microsoft.Samples.XmlRpc to project. I can connect to the service but when I try to send Soap message I am getting :

`<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:hdr="urn:PASAHeader" xmlns:ns3="urn:PASAMnfGetFlowVehInfo_v2" xmlns:ns1="urn:PASAMnfGetFlowVehInfo" xmlns:ns2="urn:PASAMnfUpdatedFromSupplier" xmlns:ex="urn:PASAexploitationWS">
              <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="_0">
                <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
                  <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:VersionMismatch</faultcode>
                  <faultstring>SOAP version mismatch or invalid SOAP message</faultstring>
                </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
              </SOAP-ENV:Body>
            </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`

I am using that code to convert to xml-rpc

```
     ChannelFactory<ServiceReference2.MnfGetFlowVehInfoPortTypeChannel> typeChannel = new ChannelFactory<ServiceReference2.MnfGetFlowVehInfoPortTypeChannel>(new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress(uriAdress)); 
        typeChannel.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new XmlRpcEndpointBehavior());
```

I tried to change the version using messageVersion in library but I couldn't handle it.Thanks

Comment: It is failing the schema check based on the namespaces :xmlns:ns3="urn:PASAMnfGetFlowVehInfo_v2"

Comment: @jdweng Could you give me more detail about failing. How can i solve that

Comment: To verify that schema check is failing.  From Visual Studio Project Menu :  Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Then paste your xml into view.  Errors will show up in the Error List like compiler errors.  Some of the namespace do not have full path names so errors in these namespaces will be ignored so you may need to add full path or move the schema file to see errors.  You xml version is not matching the schema that you are using.  So you may want to use a different schema or update the xml to correct version.

Comment: @jdweng, thanks for explanation. I'll try.

Comment: I now too late but i found problem. Problem was wrong servicereference files to send me by author.